# MySQL ReadView bug?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mvcc

This is a question about code internal to the InnoDB storage engine in MySQL 8.0 source.

In the 'ReadView::prepare' method (file read/read0read.c):

```
m_up_limit_id = !m_ids.empty() ? m_ids.front() : m_low_limit_id;
```

in the 'changes_visible' method (file include/read0types.h):

```
if (id < m_up_limit_id || id == m_creator_trx_id) {
  return (true);
}
...
if (id >= m_low_limit_id) {
 return (false);
} else if (m_ids.empty()) {
  return (true);
}
```

The logic of `m_ids.empty()` is useless, `id` cannot be less than `m_up_limit_id` and greater than or equal to `m_low_limit_id`, because `m_ids.empty()`, then `m_up_limit_id == m_low_limit_id`, I don't know if my understanding is accurate, I hope to get an answer

Comment: Can you give a github link to these lines so it's clear which file and lines you are looking at?

Comment: changes_visible : https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/include/read0types.h#L162

Comment: 'ReadView::prepare : https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/storage/innobase/read/read0read.cc#L464

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the call to `empty()` is important. The set of active transactions might be empty. In other words, the ReadView is prepared at a time when there are no active transactions.

If that is the case, the `front()` function cannot return a valid transaction id. The code in `front()` throws a debug assertion if it is called on an empty set.

Comment: I don't understand why you think this is a problem.

Comment: but,In the 'ReadView::prepare' method (file read/read0read.c):

```
m_up_limit_id = !m_ids.empty() ? m_ids.front() : m_low_limit_id; 
```
If m_ids.empty(), then m_up_limit_id == m_low_limit_id, so 'else if (m_ids.empty())' is not called

Comment: Are you seeing any problem in the behavior of MySQL because of this code? Or does it only seem redundant?